# Pythonで大学ランキングのスクレイピング

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

pythonで以下のページをスクレイピングし、大学ランキングのoverall、他要素を抽出しようと思っています。

https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/arts-humanities

selenium BeautifulSoupを用いてコードを書いたのですが、該当タブにアクセスはできるものの文字を抽出できず、困っている状況です。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver= webdriver.Chrome()

url='https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/arts-humanities'

driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
found = soup.find('div', class_='tab-content')
s = found.find('div', id='ranking-data-load_ind')
a = s.findAll('div', class_='row ind-row')
print(a)

-->[]
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

対象のウェブページの HTML ソースを眺めてみると、ランキングの部分は JavaScript で動的に生成しています。

```html
<script id="ranking-row-html_ind" type="text/html">
   <div class="row ind-row">
              :
```

なので、`div` 要素がレンダリングされるまで待つとよろしいかと思います。

以下は `Selenium 4.0.0`, `BeautifulSoup4 4.10.0` を使用していますが、`Selenium 4` から API の一部が変更されています。また、`headless` モードを指定しています。

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service as cs
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_service = cs.Service(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=opts)

url='https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2020/arts-humanities'
driver.get(url)

# wait until div tag rendered
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ind-row')))

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

found = soup.find('div', class_='tab-content')
s = found.find('div', id='ranking-data-load_ind')
a = s.findAll('div', class_='row ind-row')
print(a)

# 出力結果
[<div class="row ind-row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="_qs-ranking-data-header-new-white">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5 _right_background">
              :
```